# Why does JAXB not create a member variable in its generated code when an XML schema base type and subtype have the same element declared in them?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a question regarding with regard to JAXB generated classes.

As you can I see, I have a complex type, DG_PaymentIdentification1, declared in my schema.
Its a restriction of PaymentIdentification1. DG_PaymentIdentification1 is also identical to 
PaymentIdentification1. I also have a type called DG_CreditTransferTransactionInformation10
which has a base type of CreditTransferTransactionInformation10 and is identical to it.

I have included the relevant XML schema snippets below.

```
<xs:complexType name="DG_PaymentIdentification1">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="PaymentIdentification1">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="InstrId" type="DG_Max35Text_REF" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="EndToEndId" type="DG_Max35Text_REF" id="DG-41"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="PaymentIdentification1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="InstrId" type="Max35Text" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="EndToEndId" type="Max35Text"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="DG_CreditTransferTransactionInformation10">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="CreditTransferTransactionInformation10">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PmtId" type="DG_PaymentIdentification1"/>



<xs:simpleType name="DG_Max35Text_REF">
    <xs:restriction base="DG_NotEmpty35">
        <xs:pattern value="[\-A-Za-z0-9\+/\?:\(\)\.,'&#x20;]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


<xs:simpleType name="Max35Text">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

JAXB generates the following java class for DG_PaymentIdentification1:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DG_CreditTransferTransactionInformation10")



public class DGCreditTransferTransactionInformation10
     extends CreditTransferTransactionInformation10
{


}
```

My question is why doesnt the DGCreditTransferTransactionInformation10 generated class have a variable
of type DG_PaymentIdentification1 in the generated code? The base class CreditTransferTransactionInformation10
does have a type PaymentIdentification1 declared in it.

Is there any way of ensuring that DGCreditTransferTransactionInformation10 will have a DG_PaymentIdentification1 
in it?